# What was the fifth card of the dead man's hand?

Tags: poker-history, dead-mans-hand

What was the fifth card of the dead man's hand? Was there any proven information about fifth card of dead man's hand?

Comment: I just Googled exactly that, and this is what came up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Fifth card was a bullet to the brain, from that point on, game over, cards no longer matter...

Comment: why not the Death Lady the Q of spades

Comment: I always heard it was another black ace, thus providing the reason he was shot.

Comment: Do you have _any_ reliable evidence to support your theory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, what is the dead man's hand? From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_man%27s_hand);

[image]

> The make up of poker's **dead man's hand** has varied through the years.
> Currently, the dead man's hand is described as a two-pair poker hand
> consisting of A♣A♠8♣8♠. Along with an unknown "hole"
> card, these were the cards reportedly held by "Old West" folk hero,
> lawman and gunfighter, [Wild Bill Hickok](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_Bill_Hickok), when he was assassinated.

In the [fift card section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_man%27s_hand#The_fifth_card) on the same page;

> In accounts that mention two aces and eights, there are various claims
> regarding the identity of Hickok's fifth card, suggestions that he had
> discarded one card or that the draw was interrupted by the shooting
> and Hickok therefore **never received his fifth card**.
>
> Historical displays in the town of Deadwood, including one in a
> reconstruction of the original saloon, display the 9⋄ as
> the fifth card. The Lucky Nugget Gambling Hall, at the historic site
> of Nuttal & Mann's Saloon, displays a J⋄ instead. The
> Adams Museum in Deadwood has a display that claims to be the actual
> Bulldog Squeezers Playing Cards held by Hickok ( A⋄ , A♣, 8♥, 8♠, and the Q♥).
> The old Stardust Casino on the Las Vegas Strip had used a 5⋄
> in related displays.

As we can see, there are a lot of rumor about this subject. Also there is a web site called [DeadMansHand.us](https://web.archive.org/web/20170708081120/http://www.deadmanshand.us/);

> The earliest known reference to a dead man's poker hand is from 1886
> and it is there described as three jacks and a pair of tens. It was,
> however, not a reference to Wild Bill Hickok's hand. Although the
> evidence is lacking, it is generally "accepted" that Hickok's hand was
> A♠, A♣, 8♠ and 8♣. There are many claims as
> to what the fifth card was and there is even reason to believe that it
> had been discarded and that Bill was drawing his final card when he
> was shot dead. Whether the fifth card was queen of diamonds, jack of
> diamonds, five of diamonds, nine of diamonds or queen of clubs, all of
> which have been suggested in various contexts, it is likely that
> **Hickok was already holding the winning hand** and that the **fifth card would not have changed anything**.

tl;dr

Unfortunately, we never know what was the fifth card!

Comment: Please please give me a good reason why we (we = people, society...) care about that. A guy died while playing poker (a Draw game, it seems) and we don't know what hand he had. Why is this relevant ? Should we also start debating what color the Titanic's captain underwear was ? Maybe it was white, but he wanted black. So he got depressed and that's why made that fatal mistake...

Comment: First of all, your argument is pointless. In Stackexchange network, doesn't ask questions only that we **care**. For example, in Stackoverflow, I never asked a question tagged with `linux`, but there are a lot of **valid** questions on SO. Also this is a valid question for Poker StackExchange. When we complete our `beta` time, you can read [faq] and understand what I tried to say about this subject.

Comment: I'm not saying your question is not legitimate. I didn't downvote it and I didn't vote to close it. Although, if you really think about it, it doesn't really fit here... What would be the correct answer ? No one knows, apparently. It will generate a speculative discussion which would go nowhere... Asking about specific hands, decisions, game mechanics etc. is helpful to people who end up here (from Google probably). But is a non-answerable question about something that is basically irrelevant helpful ?

Comment: Ok, what about someone search in google "What was the fifth card of the dead man's hand?" and find this answer. Still will be irrelevant helpful? I don't think so.. Whatever, if moderators will think this question irrelevant about poker, they probably remove or close this question.

Comment: @RaduMurzea Please give me good reason why a moderator would put comments on an answer about a question.  If you have comments about the question place them on the question and feel free to vote to close.  And there is no need for language like "give me a good reason why".  You are encouraging discussion and that is not was comments are for.

Comment: @Paparazzi Radu was not a moderator _when_ we discussed this question. But honestly, with my all hearth, this discussion _still_ seems unnecessary after 4 years since this question does not get a single close vote or something.

Comment: Out of context now, but is anyone now legitimately curious as to the color of the captains underwear but me?

Comment: @JamesWilson it is very relevant and a court actually just spent hours discussing a defendant's underwears colour. Pink or Violet ? He got sentenced to 5 years for it... http://www.lemonde.fr/police-justice/article/2017/10/11/voiture-de-police-incendiee-7-des-9-prevenus-juges-coupables-jusqu-a-7-ans-de-prison-prononces_5199311_1653578.html

Comment: @RaduMurzea : the fact, established in this answer, that no-one knows (and noone will ever know) whats the fifth card was IS a relevant information. People who will get here after a Google search will understand that they don't need to look further and save time ! Otherwise, I agree with you: the nature of that card has zero importance.

Answer (score 1):

It was the 5 of diamonds more than likely, shot in back of head fall on cards, blood drips on 5 of diamonds card and make it look like 9 of diamonds. No way it could be Q, or J. come on J's wild... These are grown men that were playing not old ladies playing go fish. Try with a red marker to make a 5 look like a 9 of diamonds, then try to make it look like a Q or J, remember like blood dripping from head on cards. But know one knows he still had the winning hand and died. Sometimes when you win you really lose.

Answer (score -1):

Re: Dead Man's Hand (Wild Bill Hickock) Black Aces & Eights. 'Never know what the fifth card was'. According to 'spirits anonymous' it was the 5 of diamonds. 'Olde Stardust' in Vegas was correct!

Comment: Do you have _any_ reliable evidence to support this?

Answer (score -1):

It was a queen of hearts. The man who picked the hand up off the floor when Hickok died handed the hand down to his son. His son made a report to a news reporter that he had Black Aces and Eights with a Queen of diamonds as the kicker. Also the Queen had a drop of blood on it.

Comment: Interesting. Any links to sources that can corroborate this.

Comment: I couldn't find _any_ information about his son on Google. A proper and reliable source would be _really_ nice about this subject.

Comment: Begin of the answer is Q of hearts, end of the answer is Q of diamonds...

Answer (score -2):

The 5th card was 5 of diamonds  not a 9 of diamonds i did my research for a long time and studied the cards that bill was holding and he was holding 5 of diamonds even with the blood splatter and this is for a fact not a thory

Comment: What are your sources? There are a lot of theories as to what his card was, and even the theory that he hadn't been dealt the final card when he was shot.

Comment: I love the 'I did my research' source.